# TeXstudio list of labels on the left pane

Tags: texstudio, labels

Is there an option in `TeXstudio` which enables the display of labels in their order of appearance on the left pane?

Here is a screenshot of the case:

[image]

**MWE** https://pastebin.com/nVH3vKV2

Answer (score 3):

In the structure panel, the labels are sorted by appereance:

[image]

Comment: I noticed it now, but it does not show the labels in some cases.

Comment: I have added a screenshot as you can see chapter 6 contains labels, but they are not displayed.

Comment: @Vesnog Can you make a minimal non-working example where texstudio does not show the labels?

Comment: I have made a MWE that compiles and `Texstudio` does not show labels. Please follow the pastebin link in the latest edit.

Comment: @Vesnog Thanks for the upload. For me it shows the lables in the sidebar. Which texstudio version are you using? I have TeXstudio 2.12.4

Comment: TeXstudio 2.11.2 (hg 6192:72f68414a729)
Using Qt Version 5.6.1, compiled with Qt 5.6.1 R
on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: @Vesnog Can you update to the current version? From the change logs, there where bug fixes for labels not displayed in the structure panel.

Comment: I updated but the problem still persists.

Comment: @Vesnog Maybe fill a bug report at https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/ ?

Comment: After experimenting a little more I will do it, maybe the leftover files caused this behaviour.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS 64bit with TeXstudio 2.12.0 (hg 6348+:d88c1d5a2088+)
Using Qt Version 5.5.1, compiled with Qt 5.2.1 R
 everything is fine.

Comment: @Vesnog Might be a bug, if it works on one system but not on another.